# Failed resolution of: Landroid/databinding/DataBindingComponent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kapt

I have a kotlin android library module in my project in which I'm trying to use the DataBinding Library.  I'm using the DataBindingComponent to do some image loading.  Everything is fine at compile time, the generated DataBindingComponent interface is created and I can implement it and inject it in.  At runtime, however, the app crashes:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/databinding/DataBindingComponent;
```

From inspecting the apk of the app, and the aar of the library module, it doesn't look like the DataBindingComponent is included.

Some code snippets:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

...

android {

    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}


dependencies {
    ...
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.1"
    ...
}
```

**ImageBindingAdapter**

```
class ImageBindingAdapter(private val loadImage: (ImageView, String) -> Unit) {

    @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
    fun setImageUrl(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
        view.loadImageWhenLaidOut(imageUrl, loadImage)
    }

}
```

**Use of DataBindingComponent**

```
itemRecyclerAdapter.dataBindingComponent = object : DataBindingComponent {
    override fun getImageBindingAdapter(): ImageBindingAdapter {
        return ImageBindingAdapter({ imageView, url ->
            loadImage(imageView, url)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is most likely caused by missing ```dataBinding { enabled = true }``` in main app module. You need to add it in there in addition to the one you added to library module.

Comment: Hmm that has changed the error. I'm now getting a ClassNotFound on my generated Binding classes (created from the layout files)

Comment: @sergejshafarenka You've pointed me in the right direction though - I need to add the dataBinding stuff to each build.gradle in my dependency chain - so I've got App -> Lib -> Lib and the databinding things needs to go in all 3

Comment: Yes, this is what needs to be done to properly enable databinding in multi-module project.

Answer (score 0):

**In my experience, this issue is just a red herring.**

I just spend a couple of days trying to figure out the root cause for a similar problem.

I was converting the application to the library and turns out that since android-14 the constants in R.java not final anymore for the library.

So I had to make sure that R.id is not used in the switch statement, annotations etc.

It was hard to find out the root cause as it was deeply hidden in the tonnes of errors from databinding library as most of the annotation processors were broken.

The first thing I would recommend you to do is to increase the error display limit.
In my case, I had more than 2400 errors for the project.

This Gradle snippet saved the day:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "10000"
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxwarns" << "10000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by a missing data binding declaration in your main **app module**:

```
dataBinding { 
    enabled = true 
}
```

Credit to [sergej shafarenka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219199/sergej-shafarenka) and his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897700/failed-resolution-of-landroid-databinding-databindingcomponent#comment86816177_49897700)